# How to run a clean build for a particular project from a solution in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, command-line, msbuild

Suppose I need to build a whole solution (which has multiple projects) in command line, is it possible to run a clean build for a particular projects and run an incremental build for the rest of the project?

Thanks.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Use msbuild and pass the Clean and Rebuild targets:

```
msbuild path\to\solution\yoursolution.sln /t:Clean;Rebuild
```

Or if you only want to rebuild a single project:

```
msbuild path\to\project\yourproject.csproj /t:Clean;Rebuild
```

msbuild is available in the Windows SDK or the Visual Studio Command prompt.

Comment: Will it rebuild the whole solution or just a particular project?

Comment: Yes, you can by specifying the project file instead of the solution. See my updated answer.

Comment: MSBuild is delivered in the .NET Framework, you don't need to install the SDK

Comment: This is great. But how do I get it to rebuild the release version, not debug?

Comment: msbuild project.csproj /t:clean;rebuild /p:configuration=release

Comment: This doesn't work if the solution defines certain non-default configurations for dependency projects. You can't just call `msbuild myproject.vcxproj` then, you *need* the solution like `msbuild mysol.sln /t:myproject`. Unfortunately that doesn't seem to pair with the `rebuild` target.

Comment: in the official documentation they do not specify "/t", what is this? just wondering...

Comment: @Haris `/t` is the shorthand for the `/target` switch. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx#Switches

Comment: To locate MSBuild.exe: open a developer command prompt from Visual Studio, then type : "where msbuild"

Answer (score 14):

```
MSBuild.exe MultiProjectSolution.sln /t:"ProjectName:clean"
```

Will clean only the specified project in your solution.

Comment: Thanks! This also works and it cleans all projects that the target project name depends on but leaves other projects uncleaned.

Answer (score 5):

Just a small refinement for using in PowerShell:

```
pathTo\MSBuild.exe pathTo\solutionfile.sln /target:"clean;Build"
```

[Source For Different Target](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-targets?view=vs-2019)

Answer (score 3):

Cleaning up specific projects:

```
msbuild MyProjectFile1 /t:Clean
msbuild MyProjectFile2 /t:Clean
...
```

This has to be repeated for all projects you need to clean, because MSBuild only accepts single project on command line.

Build whole solution incrementally:

```
msbuild MySolutionFile
```

Note, that this will build default configuration/platform for the projects and solution, which is often Debug/AnyCPU or Debug/Win32. If you want specific configuration/platform, you have to add parameters like this: `/p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=x64` to every msbuild command line.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the semicolon didn't work. I solved it using comma instead after Clean target.

```
MSBuild Solution.sln /t:Clean,Build /p:Configuration=Release
```