# How do I clean only a single project?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I would like to clean a single project in the solution.  I tried selecting the project, left-clicking and choosing "Clean" from the pop-up menu.
However, when I do that, Visual Studio not only cleans the project but all projects that the target project depends on.

How do I change this behavior so ***only*** the target project is cleaned but the projects on which it depends are ***not*** cleaned?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run a clean build for a particular project from a solution in visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14367582/how-to-run-a-clean-build-for-a-particular-project-from-a-solution-in-visual-stud)